# Kafka to ES and other sink DB

Tags: database, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Using a mysql source connector, I can capture the mysql change and post to them ES or another db for backup. But for that I need separate connector(both source and sink) for each table I have in my source db.
So my question is:

Without creating same amount of source and sink connector for each tables, how can I achieve the same purpose? As this is cumbersome to create that many connectors. So that backing up db(replica) and making faster response service for clients would become much easier for me. Or there is no way to do this?

Comment: You could write a script to create both your source and sink connector property files before sending to Connect server

Comment: yes, that can be an another way too!

Answer (score 1):

For the source connectors, you can use [`table.whitelist`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/source_config_options.html#database). For example,

```
table.whitelist: "User, Address, Email"
```

---

Sink connectors can only be configured for one table at a time.

---

And I wouldn't say that it is hard to maintain multiple sink/source connectors and topics. From my experience, it is harder to maintain connectors which are replicating data from multiple topics/sources. For example, if you want to apply SMT (Simple Message Transform) on a particular topic, you won't be able to achieve it if you don't have isolated connectors as SMTs are applied on a connector level. Furthermore, if you configure a single connector for all of your sources and at some point it fails, all of your target systems will encounter downtime.

Comment: does whitelisting a list of tables conquer to copy data to same topic? from doc: `table.whitelist
List of tables to include in copying. If specified`. Isn't it